# Integrating IBM Watson Assistant to Angular js project

Tags: angularjs, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I have created chatbot service on IBM Cloud. I have my Angular project outside IBM Cloud. Now, I want to integrate Watson Assistant with my project. How to do that? Do I want to have any external jar files for this integration?

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how you deploy the chatbot and how you interact with it. You can integrate / [embed the Watson Assistant chatbot into any website similar to a widget](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-deploy-web-link) or interact with it from within your Angular app itself. In that case, you have the option to call the [Assistant API functions](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2) or to [use an SDK like the Node.js SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk).

Comment: Thanks for the response. As of now, I have added chatbox button in the UI ,Clicking on the button will redirect to chatbox in a new tab. Ideally chatbox should open in the same page itself. Now I am working on UI only..Backend code is not present. I am new to angularJs and cloud env.  so learning and developing doing together.I saw the SDK git hub link.After creating clone, How to integrate it with my current project.

Comment: So your question is not related to Watson Assistant, but on how to work with Angular and modules. The Watson Assistant SDK is just a regular Node.js module. See https://angular.io/cli/add

Comment: In bluemix , I have created assistant service .But didn't connect to any java liberty profile.Is that needed to connect to any runtime ? Can we use only service outside bluemix?

Comment: You can use Watson Assistant with any app or service inside and outside of IBM Cloud.

Comment: when I tried to export my chat service, only json file is getting downloaded.As I m new to this, not sure anything else also have to download?

Comment: I recommend to join the Watson Slack for discussion with the development team: http://wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/ Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions.